# Pushing new key value pair to json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, node.js, object

Here is my Json output

```
 "user_data": {
    "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
    "email": "a@adsfd.com",
    "password": "cool123",
  }
```

How can i add a new key value pair so that i can get

```
 "user_data": {
    "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
    "email": "a@adsfd.com",
    "password": "cool123",
    "name" : "tom"
  }
```

I tried like this

```
data.push({"name": "tom"});
```

But i am always getting the

```
 "user_data": {
    "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
    "email": "a@adsfd.com",
    "password": "cool123",
  }
```

How can i do this. Help pls

Comment: `Object.assign(data.user_data, {"name": "tom"})`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to append to user_data not the whole object another object

Try using the array notation

```
data["user_data"]["name"] = "tom";
```

or

```
data.user_data.name = "tom";
```

demo:

```js
data = {"user_data": {
    "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
    "email": "a@adsfd.com",
    "password": "cool123",
  }};
  
  data["user_data"]["name"] = "tom";
  console.log(data)
```

Comment: am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'age' of undefined
` when i try `data["user_data"]["age"] = "tom";`

Comment: your object needs to look like in the snippet

Comment: So cool! That was my first time seeing or noticing a 'code snippet' in action. Thank you for a special answer.

Answer (score 6):

simply)

```
  o = {
    "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
    "email": "a@adsfd.com",
    "password": "cool123",
  }
```

and then

```
o.name = "tom"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this, it will add your new key directly to your object

```
data.name = "tom";
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method is using to push an element to an array and not for adding a property to object.

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for copying the value from an another object or directly set the property using dot or bracket notation.

```
Object.assign(data.user_data, {"name": "tom"})
// or
data.user_data.name = "tom";
```

```js
var data = {
    "user_data": {
      "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
      "email": "a@adsfd.com",
      "password": "cool123",
    }
  },
  data1 = {
    "user_data": {
      "_id": "5806319c08756025b4c7287b",
      "email": "a@adsfd.com",
      "password": "cool123",
    }
  };

Object.assign(data.user_data, {
    "name": "tom"
  })
  // or
data1.user_data.name = "tom";

console.log(data, data1);
```